# Forcing .txt file extension in C#

Tags: c#

I've written a function that is meant to read a user's user code. Then, if a created file exists in the database, read the file into the console -- if it doesn't exist, then create the file.

However, instead of creating a `.txt` file like it's supposed to, it creates a `.FILE`. Furthermore, when the code reads the file into the console, it only outputs the `AGE` variable and not the `NAME` variable.

What have I done wrong? and how do I force it to be a `.txt` file?. Here is my `.cs` file:

```
public class Users
{
    static string age;
    static string name;
    static string user = Exercise4.personalpword;
    static string somePath = @"C:\users\jmanthony\desktop\infolder";
    static string path = Path.Combine(somePath, user);


    public static void Fn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your age?");
        age = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        age = Console.ReadLine();
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(age);
            sw.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
    public static void Conditions()
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: File does not exist, please create.");
            Fn();
        }

    }
    public static void Josh()
    {
        Conditions();
    }

    public static void User1()
    {
        Conditions();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn [how to use the debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Pay close attention to the values of `path` and `age`.

Comment: `Path.ChangeExtension(path, "txt");` to update the extension

Comment: You are reading "age" twice. Check both lines with ReadLine() calls

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Where in my code should I put Path.ChangeExtension(path, "txt");?

Comment: @OptionalOption Thanks! I didn't see that, I appreciate it.

Comment: somewhere between `path` declaration and writing to file

Comment: @DourHighArch Sorry, I just picked up c# 2 days ago, and am trying to learn programming with this and an extremely rudimentary knowledge of python as my only experience. I'm working on it, so I'm sorry to waste time.

Comment: You don't have to apologize. We all start somewhere, and advising you on a valuable debugging skill shouldn't be taken as some sort of attack that you need to apologize for. Just [learn how to use the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 1):

Your code never specifies that you want to create a text file.  You can do that with the [`Path.ChangeExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension) method in the .NET library:

```
string textFile = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(user, "txt");
```

and then use that variable in your Path.Combine invocation:

```
Path.Combine(somePath, textFile)
```

You're also incorrectly reusing your age variable and thus overwriting the user's input for their age.  This is a simple correction: change the second

```
age = Console.ReadLine();
```

to

```
name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Likely because your entire answer is just the first 3 comments on the question.

Comment: A function is not a library, and "this is a simple correction that you can do yourself"  is not helpful.  And like juharr said, your answer is basically the comments from the question itself.

Comment: I answered the question without looking at the comments.  You're not supposed to answer questions in comments.  System.IO is part of the BCL :shrug:

I suppose I could have typed the whole line of code and changed the variable name?  Seems unnecessary.

Comment: This seems like a partial answer, at best, and in its current form, is not a good answer.

Comment: It seems like a pretty standard homework question to me.  For those type of questions I feel like it's better to explain conceptually than to just correct the code and copy it back to an answer.  I feel like going any further with my second point would be exactly that.  Thanks for the feedback everyone.